# ratchetphp websocket - Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: nginx, websocket, ratchet

Can't figure out what is causing this 404 error.
Here is my code (Symfony command):

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $loop = LoopFactory::create();

    $this->newsletterConsumer->consume($loop);

    @$server = new App($this->host, $this->port, $this->host, $loop);
    $server->route('/newsletters/{id}', $this->newsletterComponent, ['*'], $this->domain);

    $output->writeln(sprintf('Web-socket server started at %s:%s', $this->host, $this->port));

    $loop->run();
}
```

here are: `host` - 127.0.0.1, `port` - 8081, `domain` - srcrm.dev

JS code:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://ws.srcrm.dev/newsletters/12');
...
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ws.srcrm.dev;
  access_log off;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Chrome Developer tool shows:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://ws.srcrm.dev/newsletters/12' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Can anybody help to understand what's wrong here?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @simPod Not yet

Comment: @xurshid29 I have this problem too...did you fix it?